# Go to home page tab on click on tab item from each and every page

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar, uitabbaritem

I need to go to home page when I click on Home tab item. Even when I am in an inside page of any tab , any page.

[image]

Note : The whole tab bar controller is embedded in a navigation controller and navigated to tab bar controller from another page.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I tried pop view controller , but if it does not work when you are in another tab.

Comment: `UITabBarController` should automatically change the tab to the one you selected. I don't really understand your problem and what you are trying to do. You should probably include your code (minimal relevant example) and describe a case that does not work as expected

Answer (score 2):

Please try to remove your view controller from navigation stack before you select another tab.

```
self.navigationController!.viewControllers.removeAll() // to remove all view controllers from stack
self.navigationController?.viewControllers.remove(at: "insert here a index") // to remove specific view controller - enter index
```

Hope it works

Cheer :)

Comment: This works partially, If i'm inside a viewcontroller which is navigated from home tab cannot use this approach